# 7388 based amplifier restarts at high volume

Tags: power-supply, amplifier, bluetooth

Please find below the quick drawing of my DIY amplifier with MIC input based using the TDA7388. The purpose is for an announcement system so stereo separation is not that important. The problem I am facing is that the system works fine in normal volume but when loud audio is played in near maximum volume the amplifier restarts.

My guess is that at high volumes, when loud audio input is played, the amplifier suddenly uses up all the current and causes the 7805 output to drop turning-off the Bluetooth module, could that be it? Or any other ideas?

[image]

Comment: so, is your power source able to supply enough current at high volume? 1A doesn#t sound like much at all.

Comment: how much amp can i use without overheating the amp?

Comment: not the problem of the amp, but of your power source. Read my comment carefully!

Comment: also, such information is given in the datasheet, which you probably already read.

Comment: How good is the heatsink? Have you investigated the amp's thermal trip logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amp automutes at 6.5v supply voltage, approx.

Your input voltage is dropping out, probably because the supply is limited to 12W but you are driving more than that into the speakers.

Note that the 7805 might also drop out around that same voltage depending on how much current your module uses.

Note you should also AC couple the audio inputs.  You haven't shown whether you have done that, but there can be problems if you do not.

You also haven't shown what you did with the standby and mute inputs.  It's possible you are tripping those, depending on what you are driving them with.

Post the proper schematics and also the resistance of the speakers.

Comment: Thanks this helped. I used a 5amp power supply and it fixed it.